# Visual Studio 2013/2015 Can't Load Azure Project

Tags: visual-studio, azure-sdk-.net

I just got a new machine, and upon installing VS2013 (and I also tried VS2015 preview), one of our projects would not open.

> The application which this project type is based on was not found. 
>   Please try this link for further information:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=441332&projecttype=CC5FD16D-436D-48AD-A40C-5A424C6E3E79

The output windows, gives this link, which is useless, and searching online for the GUID {CC5FD16D-436D-48AD-A40C-5A424C6E3E79} didn't bring anything up.

Any ideas what this could be? I have used Web Platform Installer to install the Latest Azure SDK.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that our project is based on Azure SDK 2.4, and I had incorrectly installed Azure SDK 2.5

Hopefully the GUID {CC5FD16D-436D-48AD-A40C-5A424C6E3E79} will show up in searches, if others have this same problem.

Comment: I have the Azure SDK 2.4 installed and I'm still running into the error. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: OK never mind - I had to reinstall the SDK and everything was fine. It seems like VS doesn't recognize the SDK if you install it after installing the SDK.