# Cloud Service project no longer loading

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a Microsoft Visual Studio solution that I have been using for many years for producing a new release of our software application. One of the projects has recently stopped loading.
It looks like the problem may be similar to:

[Visual Studio 2013/2015 Can't Load Azure Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556901/visual-studio-2013-2015-cant-load-azure-project)

However in that case it was a new installation of Visual Studio.

Looking in add/remove programs it appears that 'Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013' has an installed date of 19th May this year and version number 2.5.21104.1601.

What is the simplest way for me to fix this problem? Should I uninstall the Azure Tools and see if I can download and install V2.4? or do I need to install a new version of Azure SDK, as the other question suggests?

Another option I have, might be to upgrade to Visual Studio 2017. I have been reluctant to do this, as am not sure what things might break.

EDIT: I notice in Extensions and Updates there is Microsoft Azure SDK 2.9 available. Should I install this?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Phil.

Comment: Yes you should keep Azure SDK updated to keep current services running smoothly

Answer (score 1):

As you said you could try installing `Microsoft Azure SDK 2.9`.

Here is the [Microsoft Release summary for Azure SDK 2.9](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-visual-studio-azure-tools-and-sdk-2-9/). 
Before installing Azure SDK 2.9 you should read this document whether your project having all the support in this SDK. If not then you should upgrade to, VS 2017.

From a developer word, I'd say upgrade to VS 2017 where you get/support all the latest features in your hand.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try updating Azure SDK first, and see f I can get this new release out. Then I'll look at upgrading visual studio.

Comment: I have installed Azure SDK 2.9.

the project is now loading.

I chose publish and signed in, but it seems to be hanging visual studio.

Comment: Looking in the Output window, It seems to have built the WCFServiceWebRole project. It says it has started publish of the CloudService project. Latest message is Transformed Web.config, but the status bar at bottom just says Publish started and the program is unresponsive ;-(

Comment: Killed VS with Task Manager, and tried again, but same thing.
Will try rebooting.

Comment: I had to actual open properties on the project and click on the option to upgrade to the new version of Azure. Now all working fine. I wonder if this might have actually worked without having to upgrade to 2.9? Anyway, I'm happy it's working now.